# Updating OpenGL

Tags: drivers, graphics, macbook, opengl, macbook-air

I am using OpenGL to develop applications on Ubuntu, and I wanted to use "modern OpenGL" instead of using deprecated things like `glBegin`. So I ran some modern OpenGL code, and my linker couldn't find the functions... This made me think that if the deprecated functions were working and newer one's weren't, that my OpenGL version was old. I ran `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version` and found out that I was using version 3.0, and my graphics card supports version 4.1. If it helps, here are my specs:

```
MacBook Air A1465
  CPU: Dual core 1.4 GHz Intel "Core i5" processor (4260U)
  RAM: 4 GB onboard 1600 MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM
  HDD: 128 GB PCIe-based flash storage
  GPU: Integrated Intel HD Graphics 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out OpenGL 4.0 isn't supported by Linux at the time of this post. If you are having this problem you will have to wait until Mesa 11.0 is released, in which OpenGL 4.1 will be supported.